# Fibonacci sum: $\sum\limits_{k\ge0}\frac{F_{2k+1}}{2k+1}\left(\frac{2+2\sqrt{2}}{1+\sqrt{\frac{17+8\sqrt{2}}{5}}}\right)^{2k+1}(-\frac{1}{5})^k$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, closed-form, fibonacci-numbers

> Prove $$\frac{3\pi}{8}=\sum\limits_{k\ge0}\left(-\frac{1}{5}\right)^k\frac{F_{2k+1}}{2k+1}q^{2k+1}$$
>   where $q=\frac{2+2\sqrt{2}}{1+\sqrt{\frac{17+8\sqrt{2}}{5}}}$, and $F_n$ are the Fibonacci numbers. This result is from [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctan%281%2Bsqrt2%29).

My ideas as to a proof are limited. I know that this is some sort of series for the inverse tangent because $3\pi/8=\arctan(1+\sqrt{2})$, but I have never seen any series for $\arctan$ involving the Fibonacci numbers. Essentially, it comes to the explicit evaluation of the function $$f(x)=\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{F_{2k+1}}{2k+1}x^{k}.$$
Indeed, the sum in question is the value $qf(-q^2/5)$.

Potentially connected is the closed form
$$\sum_{k\ge0}F_kx^k=\frac{x}{1-x-x^2},$$
perhaps we could get some sort of $\arctan$-related integral out of this.

Could I have some help evaluating $f$? Thanks.

Comment: Well you need to evaluate the sum $f(x) =\sum_{k\geq 0}F_{k+1}x^k$ and then integrate with respect to $x$ to get $F(x) =\int f(x) \, dx=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{F_{k+1}}{k+1}x^{k+1}$ and then use the series for $F(x) - F(-x) $

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $$f(x) = \sum_{k\geq 0}F_{k+1}x^k$$ so that $$(1-x-x^2)f(x)=F_1+(-F_1+F_2)x$$ or $$f(x) =\frac{1}{1-x-x^2}$$ Integrating the above we get $$F(x) =\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{1-t-t^2}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{F_{k+1}}{k+1}x^{k+1}$$ The integrand on left side can be written $$\frac{1}{(1-at)(1-bt)}=\frac{A}{1-at}+\frac{B}{1-bt}$$ where $a, b$ are roots of $z^2-z-1=0$ and $$A=\frac{a} {a-b}, B=-\frac{b} {a-b} $$ Letting $$a=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},b=\frac{1-\sqrt {5}}{2}$$ we get $a-b=\sqrt{5}$ and hence we have $$F(x) =\frac{1}{\sqrt {5}}\log\frac{1-bx}{1-ax}$$ and $$G(x) =F(x) - F(-x) =2\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{F_{2k+1}}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}$$ Replacing $x$ by $ix$ we get $$\sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^{k}\frac{F_{2k+1}}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}=-i\frac{G(ix)} {2}$$ The sum in question is $$-i\sqrt {5}\frac{G(iq/\sqrt{5})}{2}$$ Now $$G(x) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\log\frac{1+\sqrt {5}x+x^2}{1-\sqrt{5}x+x^2}$$ and hence $$G(iq/\sqrt{5})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\log\frac{5+5iq-q^2}{5-5iq-q^2}=\frac{2i}{\sqrt {5}}\arctan\frac{5q}{5-q^2}$$ The desired sum is thus equal to $$\arctan\frac{5q}{5-q^2}$$ The fact that $5q/(5-q^2)=1+\sqrt{2}$ needs some effort and I have not been able to do so efficiently.

---

As pointed out in comments the series for $G$ diverges if $|x|>1/\phi$ or equivalently $|q| >\sqrt{5}/\phi$. The value of $q$ used in question is greater than $\sqrt{5}/\phi$ and hence the sum in question diverges.

Comment: Very very very nicely done.(+1)

Comment: [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8pywfrkblh) numerically confirms that $$\frac{5q}{5-q^2}=1+\sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: Quick question: what is the radius of convergence of $$\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(-\tfrac{1}{5})^kF_{2k+1}}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}=\arctan\frac{5x}{5-x^2}?$$

Comment: @clathratus: I think the radius of convergence should be $\min(|1/a|,|1/b|)$.

Comment: @clathratus We have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert\left(-\frac{1}{5}\right)^{n}\frac{F_{2n+1}}{2n+1}\right\rvert^{1/(2n+1)}=\frac{\phi}{\sqrt{5}},$$ which can be verified using $$F_{n}=\frac{\phi^{n}-(-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}.$$ So the radius of convergence is $\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\phi}$.

Comment: @MathIsFun7225 That seems to work. Thanks. Interestingly enough, $$\sqrt{2}-\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{1+\sqrt{5}}<0.05.$$

Comment: I found a proof for the algebraic identity. We seek a positive solution for $$\frac{5x}{5-x^2}=1+\sqrt{2}.$$ This becomes a quadratic equation of the form $ax^2+bx-c=0$ with $a,b,c>0$. The positive root of this is given by $$r_1(a,b,-c)=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4ac}}{2a}.$$ We can multiply by $\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2+4ac}}{b+\sqrt{b^2+4ac}}$ and get $$r_1(a,b,-c)=\frac{2c}{b+\sqrt{b^2+4ac}}.$$ We then use the case $a=1+\sqrt2$, $b=5$, $c=5(1+\sqrt{2})$, and we get that $q=r_1$ after some simplification.

Comment: @MathIsFun7225 Unfortunately $q>\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\phi}$, which seems to imply that the series diverges. I don't know how to remedy this.

Comment: @MathIsFun7225 okay yeah the result in the question is incorrect. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B%28%28-1%2F5%29%5Ek+%282+%281+%2B+Sqrt%5B2%5D%29%29%5E%281+%2B+2+k%29+%281+%2B+Sqrt%5B1+%2B+%284+%281+%2B+Sqrt%5B2%5D%29%5E2%29%2F5%5D%29%5E%28-1+-+2+k%29+Fibonacci%5B1+%2B+2+k%5D%29%2F%281+%2B+2+k%29%2C+%7Bk%2C+0%2C+Infinity%7D%5D+convergence) for graphical proof that the sum diverges. I guess that the result given by wolfram was an error.

Comment: @clathratus: well the formula in my answer remains valid if $|x|<\min(|1/a|,|1/b|)=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}=1/\phi$. Now I use $x=iq/\sqrt{5}$ so the series at the end should be valid for $|q|<\sqrt{5}/\phi$.

Comment: @clathratus : I have updated my answer to reflect the diverging nature of the series.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh thank you very much.